# Android pinch zoom in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, pinchzoom

I've surfed all The net but I haven't already found an Answer or a Solution.
I need to pinch zoom an element (specifically an image) in javascript (using Phonegap),but All the plugin that I've found seems to work only with iOS.
The plugins that I have tested are:
Hammer
iScroll
scripty2
jquery touchy
and the touchmove event of javascript.
These plugins do not work, or work in spurts, in Android.
I need a solution that works on both Android than on iOS
Please help me to found a solution.
I'm desperate.
Thank you.

Comment: For what android version?

Comment: I have Android 4,but I need a solution for both Android and for iOS

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [iScroll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) on Android: is that the one that doesn't work?
which are the problems you're experiencing?

Comment: the problem is that the plugin works in spurts, the zoom is late, and therefore is unusable for a user.
But if I test iScroll with Chrome browser,it works better.
But in android phonegap application the browser that is used, is the native browser of android, and I can change it.

Comment: Fine, now i understand.
the problem is mostly related to a buggy 3DTransform support in AOSP stack browser, be sure to proper set styles, but beside this, ther's little that you can do to have better performances. Last time i Checked, 4.x version had worse performances than 2.3 series.
People is asking to unify chrome and AOSP browser in order to have better support, but nothing is happening in this direction so far